# Return Stored Procedure value from invoke-sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sqlcmd

I have a stored procedure that returns a value, 0 or 1. This is required in powershell to determine the next steps the script or user should take. The problem is, I can't find any documentation on how to access that value.

Here's the powershell invoke-sqlcmd command:

```
invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Server -query (storedProcedureQuery $firstName $lastName "*" "*" "*") -ErrorVariable var | Format-Table;
```

Heres the function storedProcedureQuery:

```
function storedProcedureQuery($firstName, $lastName, $phoneExtension, $updateEmployeeRecord, $commitUpdate)
{
    "
        exec [dbo].[usp_PhoneRemoveDuplicateExtensions_upd]
        @firstName = '$firstName',
        @lastName = '$lastName',
        @phoneExtension = '$phoneExtension',
        @updateEmployeeRecord = '$updateEmployeeRecord',
        @commitUpdate = '$commitUpdate'
    "
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.